# Unable to connect to container using host network from host

Tags: networking, docker

I set up two container. Using `--net=host` both. Container A and B can access each other, also can ping host. But host can't connect to container.

It is very strange that using host network but got different IP address in host and containers.

My host ip addr is 192.168.1.106
Containers' ip addr is 192.168.65.2

My command to run the container are

```
docker run -ti -d --name fastdfs_tracker --net=host ewnit/fastdfs sh tracker.sh

docker run -ti --name fastdfs_storage --net=host -e TRACKER_IP=192.168.65.2:22122 ewnit/fastdfs sh storage.sh
```

fastdfs_storage using TRACKER_IP to get connect with fastdfs_tracker, and it works well.

Comment: For code formatting, triple backtick is not really supported here. Use single backtick for inline formatting, and four-space prefix for blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer. Host networking does not work as expected in Docker for Mac at present.